# Which referenced DLL in my C# project is trying to access internet

Tags: c#, http, dll

I am working on a C# project. One of the referenced DLL in my project is trying to access the internet and I do not know which one.

How can I find out which one ?

Is there a way to monitor which DLL is referencing/using the HTTP services ?

Comment: Could you monitor traffic using some network sniffing tool (e.g. WireShark)? If so, you could then search the host string in your references DLL (directly, if you’ve the source or indirectly using a decompiler)

Comment: How did you figure that some DLL is trying to connect to internet?

Comment: What have you done so far? Do you have any code in progress?

Comment: My firewall (Norton) is reporting and blocking the traffic. I see the notice every time I start debugging my program. I can't use WireShark because the request does not go through. And Norton is not giving much info about the request, only stating it is outgoing HTTP on port 80.

Answer (score 2):

1.Disable your network connection.

2.Start debug your code with Visual Studio. <--- wait for a while then your program may be blocked due to the network disconnection.

3.Click "Break All" button Then the code may stopped at the entrance function of the DLL which is connecting to network ...if you are
   lucky.